# Understanding template classes in c++ - problem with new-operator

Tags: c++, class, templates, new-operator

Dear all, I've been stuck with this problem now for a few days and my searches were not successful.

What I am trying to do:
I want a template reader class (VariableReader) to handle different types of variables (usually unsigned int and pointers to vector).

I started with

```
#ifndef READER_H_
#define READER_H_
#include <string>

namespace BAT {
template <typename variableType = unsigned int>
class VariableReader {
public:
 VariableReader<variableType>();
 VariableReader<variableType>(std::string varName);
 virtual ~VariableReader<variableType>();
 std::string getVariableName();
 void setVariableName(std::string varName);
 bool isValidVariableName(std::string varName);
 variableType getVariable();
private:
 std::string variableName;
 variableType variable;

};

}

#endif
```

and

```
#include "../../interface/Readers/VariableReader.h"

namespace BAT {

template<typename variableType>
VariableReader<variableType>::VariableReader() :
 variableName("") {
 // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

template <typename variableType>
VariableReader<variableType>::VariableReader(std::string varName) :
 variableName(varName) {

}

template <typename variableType>
std::string VariableReader<variableType>::getVariableName() {
 return variableName;
}

template <typename variableType>
void VariableReader<variableType>::setVariableName(std::string varName) {
 if (VariableReader::isValidVariableName(varName)) {
  variableName = varName;
 }
}

template <typename variableType>
bool VariableReader<variableType>::isValidVariableName(std::string varName) {
 return varName != "";
}

template <typename variableType>
VariableReader<variableType>::~VariableReader() {
 // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

}
```

However, although it seems to compile I can't use it within other projects. 
EDIT: forgot to post test-code:

```
#include "cute.h"
#include "ide_listener.h"
#include "cute_runner.h"

#include "Readers/VariableReader.h"
using namespace BAT;

static VariableReader<int> *reader;

void setUp(){
reader = new VariableReader<int>::VariableReader();//this is problem-line
}

void thisIsATest() {
    ASSERTM("start writing tests", false);  
}

void runSuite(){
    cute::suite s;
    //TODO add your test here
    s.push_back(CUTE(thisIsATest));
    cute::ide_listener lis;
    cute::makeRunner(lis)(s, "The Suite");
}

int main(){
    runSuite();
}
```

I get following error message:

```
Building target: BAT_Tests
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/workspace/BAT/Debug Gcov" -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -std=c99 -o"BAT_Tests"  ./src/Test.o   -lBAT
./src/Test.o: In function `setUp()':
/workspace/BAT_Tests/Debug Gcov/../src/Test.cpp:13: undefined reference to `BAT::VariableReader<int>::VariableReader()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [BAT_Tests] Error 1
```

As I understand it the linker tries to find the constructor for VariableReader, which is not explicitly defined since I want to have a general constructor only.

Please help me to understand what I am missing.

Comment: Why do you call the constructor explicitly? `reader = new VariableReader<int>();` should be sufficient

Comment: This gives me the same linker problem as before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ FAQ Lite section on [How can I avoid linker errors with my template functions?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13) shows two solutions:

1. Move the template class's methods into the `.h` file (or a file included by the `.h` file).
2. Instantiate the template in the `.cpp` file using `template VariableReader<unsigned int>;`.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it helped me to understand a bit more.
I've instantiated the template now in the c++ file. However, this seems for me like a drawback from the template concept. Why should I define a template for each type?

Anyway it works for now, I will try No. 1 later.
Thx

Comment: @Golden: you're right, it is a drawback of templates. By making it header-only, you avoid needing to explicitly specify which types it works on, at the expence of pulling in more code everywhere that uses your class. 99% of the time, though, that"s the more useful choice.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor(s) and destructor doesn't need the template arguments in it. In addition, template classes must have the full source available to compile- you can't declare the members and define them in another translation unit like you can with normal classes.

Comment: This usually means you need the implementation in the header file.

Comment: To remove the template arguments from the c'tor and d'tor worked for compilation, but not for the linking. I still have to put

template VariableReader<int>::VariableReader();

in the .cpp file.

It seems nothing is as template-like as I would like it.

Basically what I wanted is a class which takes a template to create a single private variable:
VariableReader<int> *intReader = new VariableReader();
VariableReader<vector<float>*> *floatReader = new VariableReader();
int var = intReader->getVariable();
vector<float>* var2 = intReader->getVariable();